# Spring and Netty

Tags: java, netty

I have application with Spring and Netty. The problem is that I am trying to integrate both frameworks in a way that Netty's handler will be unique for each channel.

So, component which initialize Netty server looks like:

```
@Component
public class TCPServer {

...

@Autowired
@Qualifier("messageHandler")
private MessageHandler messageHandler;

private Channel serverChannel;

public void start() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Starting TCP Server...");
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    final EventExecutorGroup customGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(100);

    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast(new Encoder());
            pipeline.addLast(new Decoder());
            pipeline.addLast(customGroup, messageHandler);
        }
    });
    Set<ChannelOption<?>> keySet = tcpChannelOptions.keySet();
    for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ChannelOption option : keySet) {
        b.option(option, tcpChannelOptions.get(option));
    }

    serverChannel =  b.bind(tcpPort).sync().channel();
    logger.info("TCP Server started.");
}
...
}
```

and handler:

```
@Component 
@Sharable 
public class MessageHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Message> {

@Autowired
private ChannelRepository channelRepository;

private CommandUtil commandUtil;

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

    channelRepository.put(channelKey, ctx.channel());
    commandUtil = new CommandUtil();
    ctx.channel().attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("commands")).set(commandUtil);

}
...
}
```

This works fine, but the problem is that Netty creates only one instance of the `MessageHandler` class and if I replace injected `MessageHandler` and put new instance each time (`new MessageHandler()`) I lose Spring context - `channelRepository` is null.

The question is how I can implement new instance of the MessageHandler for each channel and not losing Spring context (use autowired fields)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Factory for your MessageHandler.  Inject ChannelRepository into your factory, and inject the factory into your ChannelInitializer (TCPServer).

Remove @Sharable from MessageHandler, that will prevent you from accidentally using the same one in multiple channels.  You should only add this annotation if it is safe to share the same handler across channels.

Comment: How then I access `ChannelRepository` in the `MassageHandler` ?

Comment: Add a constructor to MessageHandler and pass it in from the factory to the instance being created